# rubyでtsvを処理すると途中でとまる

Tags: ruby, csv

rubyで10MBのtsvを処理すると途中で止まってしまいます。
tsvの行数は41,452ですが、以下のコードで実行すると164で止まってしまいます。

```
i = 1
CSV.foreach(filename, :col_sep => "\t", encoding: "Windows-31J:UTF-8") do |row|
  p i += 1
end
```

止まるときはエラーになどで終了されず、そのまま実行の状態で停止します。
メモリなどの問題でしょうか。
すべて同時に処理する必要はなく、1行ずつ個別に処理できれば問題なので、解決方法を教えて下さい。

Comment: foreach は一行ずつ処理しますし、仮に、一気に読み込んだとしても10MB程度なので、メモリの問題の可能性は考えにくいのですが……。
164行目に何か問題はないでしょうか？

Comment: 文字コードの変換を行わない(encoding: "Windows-31J:UTF-8" を指定しない)場合でも結果は同じでしょうか？

Comment: こちら解決しましたでしょうか？